# Rails 3 Scope with :has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

In my latest rails app I have these 3 models - `Entries`, `Politician` and `Parties`. Simply the app is for adding "Entries" for "Politicians".  Lets assume an entry has (entry `name, date`). Parties of politicians are recorded withing the Memberships model and also I record the time-frames of each memberships. So the records in memberships looks like below.

```
politician_id, party_id, date_from, date_to
```

The models

```
class Politician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :parties, :through => :memberships do
  has_many :entries
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :politicians, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :politician
  belongs_to :party
end
```

Now let's say we have Entry record of Politician id 148, `"148","My entry name", "2010-01-25"`in the table and I need to find the **Party membership of this politician** for this entry based on the dates on both the tables. Assuming in the memberships table we have these records. I think its a scope I must use here?

```
politician_id | party_id | date_from | date_to 

148 | 10 | 2012-01-22 | 2013-01-22
148 | 16 | 2010-01-21 | 2012-01-21
148 | 45 | 2009-01-19 | 2010-01-20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this way, using chained scopes, it will work for you and more flexible down the road

Add a scope to politician to find by name;

```
scope :by_name, lambda{|name| name: name }
```

Then add a scope to your membership model to find list all memberships to fit your range

```
scope :by_date, lamda{|x,y| where("date_from > ? and date_to < ?, x,y) }
```

This will allow you to say something like

```
Party.memeberships.by_date(YOURFROMDATE, YOURTODATE).by_name(YOURPOLITICIAN)
```

These are a couple ways to do this but i like the sere pare t scope for reuse illy down the road. Though it is possible to have just one scope do it all"

Comment: Because I need to find the records for a given date (using `memberships.from_date` and `memberships.to_date` ), i created the scope as follows:

`scope :membership_by_date, lambda{|date| where("(from_date <= ? and to_date >= ?) OR (from_date <= ? and to_date IS NULL)", date,date,date) }` - Do you think this is correct. The IS NULL is if someone's membership is up to date.